# Declining a flag but still addressing it?

Tags: discussion, support

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26152380/244297), I've flagged an answer that was better suited as a comment (currenly available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152380/connected-components-using-breadth-first-search/58222451#comment102873735_26152380)). The flag was declined, but still the answer was converted to a comment. I wonder why was the flag declined then?

Comment: I think I used the last option ("in need of moderator intervention") with a comment, which was probably not the optimal way to flag that.. But still, it would probably make sense to mark it as 'helpful' and leave a comment (if that's possible).

Comment: You can check how you flagged it in your flag history if you're not sure (*"I think..."*), if you picked a mod flag you can see your message as well

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current) is your flag history.

Comment: Okay, I flagged it with a message "Should be a comment". Does it explain why it was declined?

Comment: Pretty classic case of passing-the-buck.  You have far too much rep to not handle this yourself, a single DV cures 80% of all such problems.  Somebody else flagged it, review [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16028591).  Not enough reviewers so a moderator ultimately had to take care of it.  We're supposed to make their job easier, that's what they tried to tell you.

Comment: Might the problem be that your answer was downvoted due to someone else's misspelling of dequeue?

Comment: Do not use mod flags for something that can be addressed by regular flags. You're looking for the "not an answer" flag. It was likely declined to send that message.

Comment: Could the mod send that message while still not 'declining' the apparently helpful flag? With such attitude I have no motivation to flag anything on the site.

Comment: It happened to me a few times (to have a custom flag be declined or disputed yet action be taken) and I never took slight at it; it was apparent all the time that a normal flag would have been sufficient. I don't feel like mods owe me any kind of response when I flag.

Comment: Well, looks like we need to keep using the custom mod flag for that. Using NAA is bound to fail. The reviewers in that queue are trained to accept everything that looks like an attempt to answer, which this post does, so I rather have a declined mod flag with the correct action done, than a declined flag from the queue with no action whatsoever. I guess that's the well earned price for SO for making the definition of an answer so imprecise.

Comment: @Tom "answer" starts by "In addition to jedwards' answer I would suggest to ...". Don't underestimate NAA reviewers. This could be deleted from review too. Let's not (ab)use the custom flags just to bypass the normal queues

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There is the opinion here that appending information would "deviates from original intent” and should rather be a new answer. I don't know how prevalent it is, but you can see that from time to time on meta (like here on a rejected edit: [Why did this edit get rejected as "deviates from original intent"?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290017); just a quick search). Don't get me wrong, I wouldn't abuse the custom flag for fun, but there are different opinions on how to handle such cases and I don't know if a general NAA makes clear what I think should happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I declined the flag, and converted to a comment.

The reason of me declining your flag is standard in the mod UI:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags

You were right about that answer, it needed to be deleted, and (possibly) to be kept as a comment, but you have raised a *custom* flag when this should have been a "not an answer" or "very low quality" flag (leaving the moderator decide wether to convert to a comment, delete, edit, whatever).

The idea is to deter people from using custom flags when they could have used a standard flag: custom flags take a lot of time to analyze/process and we currently have a lot of them in store. You have a higher chance of a fast flag processing when using standard flags.

We also decline a lot of spam flags when we still delete the post because it's not an answer/not a good question (but not spam): wrong flag type.

I'm sorry if this demotivates you about flagging, but you have to help us more by selecting the proper flag, else our motivation processing the custom flag queue will also go down.

Comment: This is key to understanding the psychology behind moderators moderating: the custom flag queue fills us with dread because it requires context switching constantly when dealing with those flags which is mentally draining. It really helps us when users only use custom flags for the really custom stuff.

Comment: But is there any way to feedback why it was declined and action still taken? That sounds to me highly opaque and in the end probably does not fulfill its goal: pushing users to use a better flag. For a normal user it's hard to see a reason behind declining the flag.

Comment: yeah, sometimes I take extra time to decline with a custom message. Depends how full the custom queue is. For the rest, read this post :)